# readObject is not reading all element of Linkedlist from the file

Tags: java, serialization

I am able to write data (serialize Object) into the file correctly but while reading the data I am only getting the first one. What is the problem in my code? I think I am deserializing object in correct way, because I checked it in some others code,  they are also doing in the same way.

My files are like this :

**Main.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int i =0;
    int choice = 0;
    ListIterator iterator;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<Employee> employeeList = new LinkedList<Employee>();
    LinkedList<Employee> employeeArrayList ;
    File file = new File("./src/com/company/employeeInfo.txt");

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;

    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    Employee employee = new Employee();



    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Main Menu");
        System.out.println("1.Add an Employee");
        System.out.println("2.Display All");
        System.out.println("3.Exit");

        choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        switch (choice)
        {

            case 1:

                System.out.print("Enter Employee ID : ");
                employee.id = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

                System.out.println(" Enter Employee Name : ");
                employee.name = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Employee Age : ");
                employee.age = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Enter Employee Salary : ");
                employee.salary = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

                System.out.println(employeeList.add(employee));
                try{

                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(employeeList);

                    objectOutputStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException | NullPointerException exception)
                {
                    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                }

                break;

            case 2:
               try {
                   System.out.println("----Report----");
                 //  sc  = new Scanner(file);
                   fileInputStream  = new FileInputStream(file);
                   objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
                   employeeArrayList = (LinkedList<Employee>)  objectInputStream.readObject();

                   iterator = employeeArrayList.listIterator();
                    System.out.println(employeeArrayList);
                   while (iterator.hasNext())
                   {
                       employee = (Employee) iterator.next();
                       System.out.println(employee.toString() );
                   }

               }
               catch (FileNotFoundException | NullPointerException e )
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
               {
                   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
               }

               break;
               case 3:
                  try
                  {
                      objectInputStream.close();
                      fileInputStream.close();
                  }
                  catch (IOException e)
                  {
                      System.out.println(e);
                  }
                   System.exit(0);
                   break;

               }

        }


    }




}
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee  implements Serializable {

    int id;
    String name;
    int age ;
    double salary;

    public  String toString() {
        return id+" "+name +" "+age+" "+salary ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are opening the file in "append" mode. This is controlled by the boolean `true` parameter you pass to FileOutputStream constructor:

```
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
```

In the "append" mode, what you write to the file is added to the end of the file ("appended"). The existing contents of the file are not replaced, which is what you seem to want.

Solution: stop using the append mode. This will replace the old contents of the file with the new content you are writing.

```
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
```